# What is the secret of writing a fascinating and eye catching blog post?

Tags: publishing, technique, editing, blog

Yesterday I finished my first blog post! I have given lot of efforts into it, and I tried to keep it as simple as I could so that my readers of all levels could understand it. I need your tips for improving my blogs in the future.

Comment: Sorry, Swapnil, we do not offer critique here. And the secret of writing a fascinating blog post is just too broad and would require a whole book as an answer. I therefore vote to close this question.

Comment: If you think you need improvement or do not understand a specific writing technique, ask specific questions about that and we can answer you.

Comment: @SwapniPanda, you will have to edit your question so we can help you write better blogposts in a general sense. This is not the time and place for critique. If we can help you with some techniques please ask what problems you think you have :)